# Access nested items on a dictionary ansible

Tags: json, dictionary, ansible

I have a json file with server information and the applications related.

Something like this:

```
{
  "Apps": [
   {
      "AppOwner": "Me",
      "AppNm": "Vacations"
   }
  ],
  "Hostnm": "some_server",
  "Environment": "Prod",
  "OSnm": "Windows Server 2008",
  "OSManu": "Microsoft",
  "SerialNum": "VMware-42 14 e1 37 7a 63 9b 0e-43 07 15 46 64 9c 3c 12"
}
```

I want to create a list with all the applications and the servers related

For example

```
{
    "Vacations": [server1, server2]
},
{
    "other_app": [server2, server3]
},
```

For that, I have been trying the following.

```
- set_fact:
    apps: "{{ apps }} + {{ item.Apps | map(attribute='AppNm') | list}}"
  loop: "{{ server_changes }}"

- set_fact:
    apps_revised: "{{apps | unique}}"

- set_fact:
    apps_server: "{{ apps_revised | default([]) + [{item : []}] }}"
  with_items: "{{ apps_revised }}"
```

The first part of the code, will obtain all the applications with the duplicates from the json.
The second part of the code, will clean the apps with unique.
The last part its going to create a list of application with a nested list (of servers).

The problem is that I don't understand how to navigate the nested *server_changes* application list and then add the server to my new list.
Probably there is an easier way to do it, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a test data

```
server_changes:
  - "Apps":
      - {"AppOwner": "Me", "AppNm": "Vacations"}
    "Hostnm": "server1"
  - "Apps":
      - {"AppOwner": "Me", "AppNm": "Vacations"}
      - {"AppOwner": "Me", "AppNm": "other_app"}
    "Hostnm": "server2"
  - "Apps":
      - {"AppOwner": "Me", "AppNm": "other_app"}
    "Hostnm": "server3"
```

Let's simplify the data. For example

```
- set_fact:
    my_server_changes: "{{ my_server_changes|default([]) +
                           [{'hostname': item.Hostnm,
                             'applications': item.Apps|
                                             json_query('[].AppNm')}] }}"
  loop: "{{ server_changes }}"
- debug:
    var: my_server_changes
```

gives

```
"my_server_changes": [
    {
        "applications": [
            "Vacations"
        ], 
        "hostname": "server1"
    }, 
    {
        "applications": [
            "Vacations", 
            "other_app"
        ], 
        "hostname": "server2"
    }, 
    {
        "applications": [
            "other_app"
        ], 
        "hostname": "server3"
    }
]
```

Create the list of the applications

```
- set_fact:
    my_apps: "{{ server_changes|json_query('[].Apps[].AppNm')|unique }}"
- debug:
    var: my_apps
```

gives

```
"my_apps": [
    "Vacations", 
    "other_app"
]
```

Then *loop* the list of the applications, select records that *contains* the *item* and *combine* the dictionary

```
- set_fact:
    apps_server: "{{ apps_server|default({})|
                     combine({item: my_server_changes|json_query(query)}) }}"
  loop: "{{ my_apps }}"
  vars:
    query: "[?applications.contains(@, '{{ item }}')].hostname"
- debug:
    var: apps_server
```

gives

```
"apps_server": {
    "Vacations": [
        "server1", 
        "server2"
    ], 
    "other_app": [
        "server2", 
        "server3"
    ]
}
```